# Oracle Database with Java JDBC Batch Inserts - insert child before parent

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have an Oracle (11) database with a table that has a self-referencing constraint.

I have some REALLY HORRIBLE java code, that has been happily running for a long time, that creates a BATCH of two inserts and runs them. This part of our UNIT TEST code and has been happily running for years.

The strange thing is that the insert of the CHILD is added to the batch before the insert of the PARENT.

I'd have thought that would never work. But it does

Well, it works on my original database, but not on a new "copy".

So my table is like this:

```
create table my_table (primary_key_id INT not null, related_id INT null);

alter table my_table add primary key (primary_key_id);

create index fk_my_table on my_table (related_id);

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT fkc_my_table FOREIGN KEY (related_id) REFERENCES my_table (primary_key_id);
```

The JAVA code is like this:

```
public void wossupDoc(Connection con) throws Exception {      
  String sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (primary_key_id, related_id) values (?,?)";      
  try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)){
    ps.setLong(1, 100);
    ps.setLong(2, 101);
    ps.addBatch();        
    ps.setLong(1, 101);
    ps.setNull(2, Types.NUMERIC);
    ps.addBatch();        
    ps.executeBatch();        
  }
```

(I created that table and put this java code into a unit test exactly like this so I could run it repeatedly against the different database)

So this code WORKS when run against DATABASE "A", but doesn't work when run against DATABASE "B".
So, that's the same code, the same JDBC drivers, but a different URL in the database connection properties... Yes it's always autocommit=false.

I've confirmed that, in the scenario where it works, there are two records in the database table.

The databases were created by two different DBAs a number of years apart, and they are *nearly* identical ... But are obviously different somehow.

Database versions:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

(Yes I know those are REALLY OLD versions, I'm trying to migrate our code to an Oracle 19 database, and that's how I've discovered this scenario)

Does anyone know WHY this ever worked? Is there a database/connection parameter I could tweak to turn it on or off??

My true problem is that I'm wondering whether I've got any "batching" code in the main app that might try to do this, and so has been working accidentally for the past few years; and I won't know until we go live with the new database and the users start doing things...

Comment: Is the constraint deferred on the old database, and not on the new database? Not sure it should matter with child and parent in the same batch, but just a thought...

Comment: Good idea... However I used those SQL above to create the minimum test case. There is no difference between the constraints created in either database. Unless there's some property of the database that can affect them?
Is there some Oracle database property that can make a "NOT DEFERRED" constraint act deferred?

Comment: As I investigate further, this looks like its a behavioural change in Oracle between 11.2.0.3.0 and 11.2.0.4.0.
Checking more recent versions of Oracle the behaviour is consistent - the entries in the batch have to be valid based upon the sequence they are added to the batch.  Looks like I have to accept this behaviour and fix the code/data that's failing. Makes sense, but more work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I investigate further, this looks like its a behavioural change in Oracle between 11.2.0.3.0 and 11.2.0.4.0. Checking more recent versions of Oracle the behaviour is consistent - the entries in the batch have to be valid based upon the sequence they are added to the batch. Looks like I have to accept this behaviour and fix the code/data that's failing. Makes sense, but more work for me.

Given 11.2 is so old a version of Oracle, no one else should really be getting similar problems. Thanks to everyone who looked at the question...